# SVN: How to replicate Tortoise's multi-project commit on the commandline

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit, multi-project

I have found similar questions, but none is definitely answering my question. I read, e.g.:
[How can I commit multiple directories at once using subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878834/how-can-i-commit-multiple-directories-at-once-using-subversion) 
[Commit several projects in Eclipse SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18353586/commit-several-projects-in-eclipse-svn) 
[How can I do a single SVN commit across multiple externals at the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769236/how-can-i-do-a-single-svn-commit-across-multiple-externals-at-the-command-line)

Our company convention requires two projects of the same repository checked out into **separate working copies**

```
> svn co https://svn/A/trunk Alocal
> svn co https://svn/B/trunk Blocal
```

The two projects depend on one another and so it's nice to be able to commit both in **one single revision**.

My MSWindows-using office mates use TortoiseSVN. They just multi-select both Alocal and Blocal in the windows explorer and do right-click -> commit. Done.

On the commandline, I am failing to do the same.

```
> svn ci -m '' Alocal Blocal
svn: . is not a working copy
```

The only thing I can do is to commit the two projects sequentially, resulting in two revisions.

**Is there a way to replicate TortoiseSVN's single-commit behavior with the svn commandline tool, yes or no? If yes, how?**

Thanks a lot!

PS: I'm a simple svn user. So everything involving properties (I read clutter about svn:external) or higher stuff would need some explanation or reference.

Comment: Maybe Tortoise SVN is internally doing two commits?

Comment: No. After a multi-project TortoiseSVN commit, the revision number has increased by exactly 1.

Comment: Maybe it's done with `--targets` command line option.

Comment: You say, specify each and every changed file separately? Might be. Need to test this. But, does target work for changes in the file tree, too?

Comment: Maybe it's sufficient to specify just directories, not all files. I haven't tried it (I use Tortoise, like your colleagues).

Comment: Just tested. --targets does not work, even when specifying single files. Still getting error: "svn: . is not a working copy"

Comment: Maybe svn is right. Maybe . indeed is not a working copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"separate working copies" + "one single revision" is impossible in pure SVN by design

United WC (by checkouting from common parent or linking with exernals /better and more natural way/) is **a must**.

TortoiseSVN uses here some cheat and pre-processing of data before commit, definitely